# iphone screen size with status and nav bar?

Tags: iphone

hi there can someone just confirm the exact size of the remainder of the iphone screen with a status bar and nav bar shown. i'm just trying to make a template to work off so i know how much room i have to play with.

iphone screen = 320 x 480
status bar - 20px
nav bar - 44px

so portrait i have 320 x 416
and landscape 256 x 480

is all that correct, it just doesn't seem right to me especially the lanscape measurements

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` gives you the area sans status bar. You'll have to make further adjustments for the nav bar i.e. 44px.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the numbers I've used in my projects. Keep in mind though that you should try to design flexibly (i.e. not rely on absolute positioning), so if it changes in the future you don't have to make major changes to follow the new resolution.

Answer (score 0):

you could download an existing template:

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2009/06/18/iphone-gui-psd-30/

and work from there if you are unsure

Comment: thanks guys, good point on the not using absolute positions

 - - that photoshop template comes up with an error about missing fonts, any idea where these are?

Comment: Probably on the computer that made the template :) what fonts are they? If you're more specific about your questions, we can be more helpful in our answers.

Comment: oops meant to say what fonts are they, Helvetica Neue was the answer incase anyone was interested

:)